# Developing a Chrome Desktop App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I would like to get a good tutorial on building a chrome desktop app.

I found some good ones for Chrome Extensions, Chrome Apps that don't do anything but redirecting to a website - What I want is an app like Any.do, like Google Keep, like Sunrise Calendar:
Apps that work without chrome and in a different window, but I hope I can make one with HTML-CSS-JS.

Do you know where I can find any documentation for that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was previously called a "packaged app", and now is simply called "Chrome App", as opposed to what's called "hosted app" (link to a website).

The main documentation is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/).

Note that Chrome Apps have, in some regards, more power, but they don't integrate much with the browser as Extensions do. They are intended to behave as self-contained. They don't work completely without Chrome, but they do have independent windows.

Comment: Chrome Apps deprecated and to be removed no,,?